# How can I color a square div with two colors?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="lugares">
    <tr>
        <td class="seat-avaliable"><div></div></td>
        <td class="seat-avaliable"><div></div></td>
        <td class="seat-avaliable"><div></div></td>
        <td class="seat-avaliable"><div></div></td>
        <td class="seat-not-avaliable"><div></div></td>
        <td class="seat-badvis"><div></div></td>
        <td class="seat-avaliable"><div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is a "seat-not-available" with background black, seat-available with green background and I want to add a seat (seat-badvis) with two colors, half black and half white. I tried with `:after` and `:before` but it doesn't work.

Here's the fiddle with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/g8p9pn1v/38/

Comment: Remember to accept one of these answers so that we know that this question has been answered and your problem solved successfully.

Comment: @PauloFrutuoso did any of proposed solution solve your problem? If yes then please accept this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use pseudo-selectors here, use linear-gradient instead:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 50%,#000 50%);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dbbtxL50/

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use linear-gradient:

```
.seat-badvis div {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #5e6461 50%, white 50%);
}
```

Here is a fiddle with background so it's easier to see the difference -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6shb5duo/)

Check browser compability if you're targeting older browsers [compability table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

Answer (score 1):

You can use linear-gradient for the effect. Use the color codes on various color stop levels. The direction is set `to right` for your problem.

```
.seat-badvis div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, #000 51%, #fff 51%, #fff 100%);
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

```css
.seat-avaliable div,
.seat-not-avaliable div,
.seat-badvis div {
  height: 12px !important;
  width: 12px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.seat-selected div {
  height: 12px !important;
  width: 12px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffc720;
  border: #5e6461 solid 1px;
}
.seat-avaliable div {
  background: #05cd7a;
}
.seat-not-avaliable div {
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
.lugares td {
  padding: 2px!important;
}
.seat-badvis div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, #000 51%, #fff 51%, #fff 100%);
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<table class="lugares">
  <tr>
    <td class="seat-avaliable">
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="seat-avaliable">
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="seat-avaliable">
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="seat-avaliable">
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="seat-not-avaliable">
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="seat-badvis">
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="seat-avaliable">
      <div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background gradient:

```
.seat-badvis div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);/* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);/* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)));/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);/* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);/* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);/* W3C */
}
```

see this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g8p9pn1v/42/)

If you want, you can change the direction of the color as well.

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g8p9pn1v/43/) and use this [link](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+49,ffffff+50) for a superb gradient generator.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple gradient and remove the before and after. I also added a border, in case you want it.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8p9pn1v/41/)

```css
.seat-avaliable div, .seat-not-avaliable div, .seat-badvis div {
    height: 12px !important;
    width: 12px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.seat-selected div {
    height: 12px !important;
    width: 12px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffc720;
    border: #5e6461 solid 1px;
}
.seat-avaliable div {
    background: #05cd7a;
}
.seat-not-avaliable div {
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}

.seat-badvis div {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, blue 50%); /* metade vermelho, metade azul*/
    border: 1px solid black
}

.lugares td {
    padding:2px!important;
}
```

```html
<table class="lugares">
    <tr>
        <td class="seat-avaliable">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="seat-avaliable">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="seat-avaliable">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="seat-avaliable">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="seat-not-avaliable">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="seat-badvis">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="seat-avaliable">
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```